# gcc doesn't compile C How To Program 'create a random access file' tutorial

Tags: gcc, gedit, c

The tutorial on File Processing in C How To Program 6th Edition (Chapter 11
Fig. 11.11) creates a random access file sequentially. fwrite and fread are used in the code to create 100 blank records using structs.

The problem is that after compiling using gcc:

gcc myprogram.c -o myprogram

Why is 'myfile.dat' (using gedit) opening with the following error message:

> The file you opened has some invalid characters. If you continue editing this file you could corrupt this document.Character Encoding: Current Locale(UTF-8)

Is gcc the issue or gedit? Can someone please recommend a compiler or text editor suitable for C programming in Linux. Thank you.

Comment: Your title says "doesn't compile" but the body of your question seems to be about a problem with the program's *output* - which is it? what does the `file` command say about the content (i.e. run `file myfile.dat`)?

Comment: You may have used a special character, which is normally normal in HTML and SQL. First: Check your code
Second: Try to compile with `gcc -o foo foo.c -lm`
And specialy y recomend you try to put **myprogram** (how you want to call the exe) in myprogram.c (the file that you want to compile) then compile.